# C++ Member Declaration not found

Tags: c++

I am an amateur c++ coder, and I started to use classes and Objects. I wanted to create a little "Program" that took in the birthday and name of the person and displayed it. I created a program you just enter the day, year, and month of your birthday and name & it displays it. I keep getting an error in People.h and People.cpp saying: 
**"Member declaration not found"** error, and 
**candidates are: std::People::People(const std::People&)   People.h** 
and 
**prototype for 'std::People::People()' does not match any in class 'std::People'   People.cpp**

I included Birthday.h and Birthday.cpp in two images at the bottom if you need those. Sorry for my messy formatting, this is my second post and i tried to make things readable, but I kinda failed. :P

```
My Main.cpp is:

#include "Birthday.h"
#include "People.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    Birthday birthObj(4,16,2002);

    People ethanShapiro("Ethan Shapiro", birthObj);

    return 0;
}

People.h is:

    #ifndef PEOPLE_H_
#define PEOPLE_H_
#include <iostream>
#include "Birthday.h"
#include <string>

namespace std {

class People {
    public:
        People(string x, Birthday bo);
        void printInfo();
    private:
        string name;
        Birthday dateOfBirth;
};

}

#endif

People.cpp is:

    #include "People.h"

namespace std {

People::People(): name(x), dateOfBirth(bo) {
}

void People::printInfo(){
    cout << name << " is born in";
    dateOfBirth.printDate();
}

}
```

[Birthday.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frJUF.png)
[Birthday.cpp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6QfI.png)

Comment: You should probably not put your own classes in `namespace std`. Not that it's the problem, but it goes against the purpose of namespaces (use your own namespace instead of trespass on the namespace of the C++ standard).

Comment: What do you mean by (using my own namespace instead of trspass on the the namespace of C++ standard? Does that mean creating a new namespace like **using namespace peo** to put people in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sole constructor of `People` is declared as:

```
    People(string x, Birthday bo);
```

and you are defining a constructor as:

```
People::People(): name(x), dateOfBirth(bo) {
}
```

The definition does not match any declaration.

You need to use:

```
People::People(string x, Birthday bo): name(x), dateOfBirth(bo) {
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :). I only have one question, why do i need to declare the string and object as a member (or put the colon) after putting it in the parenthases.

Comment: Are you talking about the use of `name(x), dateOfBirth(op)` after the `:` in the constructor definition?

Comment: @EthanShapiro `People::People(string x, Birthday bo)` and `: name(x), dateOfBirth(bo)` are both for different purposes. The former specifies that the constructor will be called with the parameters `string` and `Birthday` while the latter just initializes the members of the class `name` and `dateOfBirth` with the arguments passed in the constructor function. An equivalent way to do this is: `People::People(string x, Birthday bo){ name = x; dateOfBirth = bo; }`.